# Partial derivative of a function wrt another function

Tags: calculus, partial-derivative

Consider functions $f(g, h)$, $g(x, y)$, and $h(x,y)$. Now, I know what the form of $f$ is in terms of $x$ and $y$, but I'm interested in seeing how $f$ changes wrt $g$ and $h$; i.e., I'm looking to compute $\frac{\partial f}{\partial g}$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial h}$.

Is it simply
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial g}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}
\bigg(\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}\bigg)^{-1}
+ \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}
\bigg(\frac{\partial g}{\partial y}\bigg)^{-1}?
$$

Comment: Welcome to MathSE. What does $\frac{\partial f}{\partial g}$ mean?

Comment: Thanks! It's the change in $f$ as $g$ changes? I've modified my question a bit to maybe clarify what I'm after.

Comment: $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial g}$ is the partial differentiation of bivariate function $f$ with respect to its first argument, when the arguments are themselves bivariate functions $g, h$ of variables $x,y$ .

Answer (score 2):

By the chain rule, we actually have two equations:
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial g} \frac{\partial g}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial h} \frac{\partial h}{\partial x}$$
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial g} \frac{\partial g}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial h} \frac{\partial h}{\partial y}$$
I assume that you know what forms $g$ and $h$ take explicitly in terms of $x$ and $y$. Then, the above becomes a matter of solving both equations simultaneously for what you want. One could imagine expressing the above in better notation or being much more precise about domains etc. However, I'm going to assume that you're just looking for some rough work.

Answer (score 0):

To intuitively capture the notion of the rate of change of $f$ with respect to $g$ you have to reformulate your question. This is what you actually mean, I gather:

Suppose you have three functions $f(x,y)$,$h(x,y)$,$g(x,y)$. To capture the notion of $$\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial g}$$

You need to do the following: invert $x,y$ in terms of $g,h$ i.e., write $x(g,h),y(g,h)$ then plug them in $f$: $$f(x(g,h),y(g,h))$$

Now derive with respect to $g$: $$\dfrac{\partial f (x(g,h),y(g,h))}{\partial x}\dfrac{\partial x(g,h)}{\partial g}+\dfrac{\partial f (x(g,h),y(g,h))}{\partial y}\dfrac{\partial y(g,h)}{\partial g}$$ which is similar to your expression indeed.

**Example to confirm this intuition**:

Consider the function $f(x,y) = (x+y)^2$

Let $h(x,y) = x$, $g(x,y) = x+y$.

Intuitively (in informal notation) $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial g} = \dfrac{\partial (x+y)^2}{\partial (x+y)} = 2(x+y)$

You formalize it using the procedure above: write $x,y$ in terms of $h,g$: $$x(h,g)=h$$ $$y(h,g)= g-h$$ $$f(x(g,h),y(g,h)) = g^2$$

Hence $$\dfrac{\partial f (x(g,h),y(g,h))}{\partial g}=2g$$ confirming our intuition.

Note that you can do that as long as you can invert $x,y$.

Answer (score 0):

$f$ is a dependent on $g,h$ which in turn are dependent on $x,y$.

For this case, the chain rule is often presented as the two equations :$\def\bmatrix#1{\begin{bmatrix} #1\end{bmatrix}}\def\parts#1#2{\dfrac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}}$
$$\parts fx =\parts fg\parts gx+\parts fh\parts hx\\\parts fy=\parts fg\parts gy+\parts fh\parts hy$$

So we may use matrix inversion to find the $\parts fg,\parts fh$ , if we *for some reason* cannot find it directly yet know all the partials respective to $x,y$.

$$
\begin{align} \bmatrix{\parts fx\\\parts f y}&=\bmatrix{\parts gx&\parts hx\\\parts gy&\parts hy}\bmatrix{\parts fg\\\parts fh}\\[2ex]\bmatrix{\parts fg\\\parts fh}&=\bmatrix{\parts gx&\parts hx\\\parts gy&\parts hy}^{-1}\bmatrix{\parts fx\\\parts fy}\\[1ex]&=\dfrac 1{\parts gx\parts hy-\parts hx\parts gy}\bmatrix{\parts hy&-\parts hx\\-\parts gy&\parts gx}\bmatrix{\parts fx\\\parts fy}\\[2ex]\parts fg&=\cfrac{\parts hy\parts fx-\parts hx\parts fy}{\parts hy\parts gx-\parts hx\parts gy}\\[2ex]\parts fh&=\cfrac{\parts fy\parts gx-\parts fx\parts gy}{\parts hy\parts gx-\parts hx\parts gy}\end{align}$$

Comment: **Note:** This obviously requires the determinant of the matrix to be non-zero.